# Solve an equation of the prime counting function

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The problem is,

> Find all the positive integral values of $x$ for which we have, $$\pi(p_n-x)=\pi(p_{n+1}-x-1)$$where $\pi(x)$ denotes the number of primes not exceeding $x$.

I don't know where to start. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is $n$ fixed (but arbitrary), or shall that equality hold for all $n$?

Comment: Maybe the place to start is with trying some integral values of $x$ to see which ones work and which ones don't.

Comment: @DanielFischer: $n$ is fixed (but arbitrary).

Comment: Where does this question come from? It seems completely arbitrary to me. There is  hardly any insight to be gained beyond recalling the notation. The only answer is mostly restating the assertion.

Comment: So, have you taken up the suggestion in my comment?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Yes. But I am still trying to figure out how this would solve this problem.

Comment: I didn't say it would solve the problem; I said that maybe it was a place to start (you did write that you didn't know where to start, and that any help would be appreciated). So, what did you find out when you took up my suggestion? For which positive integers $x$ did the equation hold? For which ones didn't it hold?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I have observed something which is very much trivial. If $p_n-x$ is composite the the equation reduces to the form $\pi(p_n-z)=\pi(p_{n+1}-z)$ which doesn't seem to hold for $p_{n}-p_{n-1} \ge z \ge 1$ if $p_{n+1}+p_{n-1} \ge 2p_{n}$.